# How to redirect in Nginx hidding the redirect path

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have the next URL:

`https://my-web.com/path1` and I would like to redirect the call to `https://my-web/path2` but I would like that in the browser tab show's `/path1`. Is this possible?

I'm using a virtualhost in `Nginx 1.16`. I'm using a rewrite, but the problem is that in the browser tab it shows `/path2` and I need `/path1` but with the content of path1.

EDIT:

My vhost cfg:

```
server {
    root /var/www/myweb.dyndns.org;
    server_name myweb.dyndns.org www.myweb.dyndns.org;
    include global/global.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;
    rewrite ^/path1(.*)$ http://myweb.dyndns.org/path2 redirect;
}
```

Comment: Show config. Probably you're doing something wrong. This is basic nginx functionality.

Comment: hello @AlexeyTen I just edit the OP

Comment: `redirect` issues a HTTP redirect response back to the client. Most likely you want `break` or `last` instead for an internal rewrite.